# jQuery : Regex not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validateGSTNumber', function(name, element) {
    return name.match(/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/);// regex 
}, ' ');
```

I am using above function to validate GST Number. It passes almost all cases. But some cases like:

22AAAAA0000A1A5,22AAAAA0000A0A5

are also passing which should not pass.
I am unable to find problem. Any idea?

Comment: You may need to use `RegExp.test` instead of `match`.

Comment: BTW, `{1}` is not required.

Comment: `22AAAAA0000A1A5` should not pass the test. not matching that Z `[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}`

Comment: What is the GST Number pattern requirements? Using `String#match` or `RegExp#test` is of secondary importance, the main problem is to understand what kind of strings must succeed and which ones should fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the test function replace the match.like:

22AAAAA0000A1A5,22AAAAA0000A0A5

are also passing which  not pass.

```
  return new RegExp(/^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}[1-9A-Z]{1}Z[0-9A-Z]{1}$/).test(name)
```

Comment: tried. still not working for above cases. I don't understand why?